# How to get a sub parameter of JSON

Tags: c#, json, parsing

Sorry for the ambiguous title but I don't know how to explain better.
Anyway, I made a code for parse a Json in c#, this structure:

```
{
 "_links": {
   "self": { "href": "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354" },
   "teams": { "href": "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/teams"      },
   "fixtures": { "href": "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/fixtures" },
   "leagueTable": { "href": "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/leagueTable" }
},
"caption": "Premier League 2014/15",
"league": "PL",
"year": "2014",
"numberOfTeams": 20,
"numberOfGames": 380,
"lastUpdated": "2014-12-21T10:47:43Z"
}
```

in my code I can get the value of `"self"`, `"teams"`, `"fixtures"` and `"leagueTable"`. But how you can see in the structure of Json this parameter have a link associated. I want to grab this link because I need for next parsing data.

How to get this?

Actually, this is my code:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string requestUrl = "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons";
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        string responseText;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        using (var responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseText = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
        }

        List<RootObject> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseText);
        LinksClass link = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LinksClass>(obj._links);
        //89a6ba3f0a6f455b9313107d977f4a43
        foreach (var item in obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                              item.Year + " " +
                              item.League + " " +
                              item.Caption + " " +
                              item.NumberOfGames + " " +
                              item.NumberOfTeams + " " +
                              item.LastUpdated);
        }
    }


    public class Self
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Teams
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fixtures
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class LeagueTable
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Links
    {
        [JsonProperty("self")]
        public Self Self { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("teams")]
        public Teams Teams { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("fixtures")]
        public Fixtures Fixtures { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("leagueTable")]
        public LeagueTable LeagueTable { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("_links")]
        public Links Links { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("caption")]
        public string Caption { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("League")]
        public string League { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Year")]
        public string Year { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("numberOfTeams")]
        public int NumberOfTeams { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("NumberOfGames")]
        public int NumberOfGames { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("LastUpdated")]
        public string LastUpdated { get; set; }
    }

    public class LinksClass
    {
        [JsonProperty("self")]
        public Self Self { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("teams")]
        public Teams Teams { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("fixtures")]
        public Fixtures Fixtures { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("leagueTable")]
        public LeagueTable LeagueTable { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How you can see I've created this:

```
LinksClass link = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LinksClass>(obj._links);
```

and appropriate class for get this link, but I can't get the link and this way is wrong I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually already have all the link values with the first deserialization, no need for the second call to `DeserializeObject`:

```
List<RootObject> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseText);

foreach (var item in obj)
{
    //This is how you access the links:
    Console.WriteLine(item.Links.Self.href + " ");
}
```